# Only output header and summary with robocopy.exe

Tags: robocopy, syntax, progress

I'm using Robocopy and just want it to output the header and summary, hiding everything else. I've looked at the [Robocopy syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) and have tried: `/NC /NFL /NS /NDL /NP`

However I'm still getting this:

```
11 - -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12 - ROBOCOPY :: Robust File Copy for Windows
13 - -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14 - Started : Wed Jul 27 12:14:06 2011
15 - Source : C:\aaa
16 - Dest : \\xx.xxx.xx.xx\aaa\
17 - Files : *.*
18 -
19 - Options : *.* /NS /NC /NDL /NFL /S /E /COPY:DAT /NP /MT:128 /R:1000000 /W:30
20 - ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
21 - 
0%
100%
100%
100%
100%
100%
100%
22 - ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
23 - Total Copied Skipped Mismatch FAILED Extras
24 - Dirs : 1 0 1 0 0 19
25 - Files : 6 6 0 0 0 27
26 - Bytes : 372 372 0 0 0 64.0 k
27 - Times : 0:00:00 0:00:00 0:00:00 0:00:00
28 - Ended : Wed Jul 27 12:02:55 2011
```

How can I get rid of the `0% 100% 100% 100%`? It seems `/NP` is not doing its job.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's because of `/mt:`.  For some reason `/np` seems to be ignored when using multi thread. Try logging with `/log`.  It at least lists the percentages horizontally in the log file.